# Reference for supported IDL types

Tags: anchor-lang, idl, anchor-program-idl

Is there a reference for supported anchor IDL types, just like we have for the space reference. Trying to use a slice [usize; 32] but getting the error

```
IdlError: Type not found: {"type":{"defined":"usize"}}
```

To add to this, how can I pass in "bytes" from the anchor client side.
The parameter is defined like this on my anchor program

```
fn dummy(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> Result<()> {}
```

Comment: From line 111 to line 155, https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/packages/anchor/src/idl.ts#L111

Comment: @Serban you're a lifesaver. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `u8` slice instead of `usize`, the latter has a variable size depending the system. All primitives are supported, and your own structs made of primitives, and a few other types like Pubkey, the rest is a hard maybe.

On the TS client side, you can pass a `number[]` or a Buffer.